# A building with height D shadow up to G. What is the height of a neighboring building with a shadow of C feet?

Tags: geometry

[image]

A building with height D shadow up to G. What is the height of a neighboring building with a shadow of C feet?

**MyApproach**

If sun rays falls on the building at an angle say z,then tan(z)=D/G

where G(shadow) and D(height) are given:

For Any other angle tan(z)=C/x

C/x=D/G=>x=GC/D

> Is my approach right towards the problem.Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: Related question [**here**](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758066/calculate-the-height-of-a-building/758108#758108)

Comment: @K.Rmth Using the above mentioned link approach.I got the Ans DC/G.Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

I have another approach than proving it trigonometrically prove it by similarity of triangles let the shadow be cast on two sides. Draw peroendicular lines to ground which represent buildings which will be  parallel to each other. Here WE PROVE triangle AOL is similar to triangle ANM. NOTE HERE AO is the shadow of building C and AN is the shadow of building D. MN IS THE BUILDING D AND OL IS BUILDING C .  Let height of building C be $'x'$. Thus by similarity ratio of all sides is equal so $\frac{AO}{AN}=\frac{OL}{MN}$ substituing values we get $\frac{C}{G}=\frac{x}{D}$ thus height of OL is $x=\frac{CD}{G}$ . Hope it helps you. The method is known as shadow reckoning. Sun rays are considered to be parallel for such questions.

Comment: can you draw a diagram to explain your ans?

Comment: Can you tell me how to give pics here.

Comment: Sorry but can you compare with vikrams drwawing mine one is the same.Just the method differs.

Comment: No problem.Your Ans is correct.Though I need to learn the trick.

Comment: I think vikram deleted his Ans.I am not able to see it?

Comment: Sorry but i will make you stretch your imagination overlap the smaller triangle from you diagram over bigger one and then use my answer as a referrence . Surely you will get it name the common angle as A.